# How to position a div off the screen and bring it back on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

here is the fiddle of the code I am using: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/GQzEn/1/), due to an overlapping error preventing the a.trigger from working in IE I need to position the div.pop-up off the screen until the a.trigger is hovered over.

Anyone know how to do this

Comment: This example is working but the one on the site has more content in the pop ups and where they overlap even though there not displayed it causes a bug in IE which prevents to anchor .trigger from working correctly so I want to position them off screen untill they are hovered

Comment: he means this (http://jsfiddle.net/GQzEn/21/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of an old school hack at it. You simply position the element off screen to the left by 1000px and then bring it back just before you do your animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //If Javascript is running, change css on product-description to display:block
    //then hide the div, ready to animate
    $("div.pop-up").css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'})

    $("a.trigger").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).prev().css("left", "0px");
        $(this).prev().stop().animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 500);
      },
      function () {
        // First answer had this line coming first.
        // $(this).prev().css("left", "-1000px");
        $(this).prev().stop().animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 200);
        // It should actually probably be here
        // so the movement is still done invisibly
        $(this).prev().css("left", "-1000px");
      }
    )
  });​
```

You'll also need to add the positioning to the left in the css.

```
/* HOVER STYLES */
div.pop-up {
  /*display: none;*/
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;      // <--- Send me left
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0px 13px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

See me in action -> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQzEn/23/)

Comment: That looks great just let me try it and ill get back to you

Comment: everything works fine only problem is when you mouse off the outside locations you get a flicker of the pop up on the far left of the screen is there a work round for this?

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe: In hindsight, the order should probably be reversed in the hiding method. Animate, THEN move left. I'll post an update with a comment.